# Windows Server 2008 R2 release date

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Is Windows Server 2008 R2 out for general release?  Does anyone know the Release date?

Comment: ServerFault FTW!! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2 is already released.
Windows Server 2008 R2, was released on October 22, 2009.
And I have to support Jon, that you should ask such kind of questions on ServerFault.com.

Comment: Never heard of ServerFault.com, but thanks and will keep these type of questions for there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_2008_r2) generally the best source of release dates.
Much easier than going to Microsoft I've found.

Generally they are listed in the primary info bar on the right.

Useful information such as current version and dictiontion between RTM (Released To Manufacturing / completed and available to MSDN subscribers) and Retail (available to buy in a store).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_2008_r2

```
Release date    RTM: July 22, 2009
Retail: October 22, 2009 (info)
Current version 6.1 (Build 7600)
(6.1.7600.16385.090713-1255[1])
(October 22, 2009; 8 months ago) (info)
```